# Rails way to write abstracted DateTime calculated SQL condition

Tags: ruby, activesupport

I am trying to write a proper Rails abstracted SQL statement equivalent to:

`SELECT * FROM model WHERE DATE_SUB(date_field, INTERVAL 7 DAY) < CURDATE()`

While I know can write the string SQL in Rails to be executed, it would be nice to be able to write it in some abstract way that keeps my code database platform agnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple, in fact:

```
Model.all( :conditions => [ "date_field BETWEEN ? AND ?", 7.days.ago, Date.today ])
```

And you have it.

Comment: A more Rails 3 happy way is: `Model.where("date_field BETWEEN ? AND ?", 7.days.ago, Date.today).all`

Answer (score 0):

Squeel power FTW!!!

$ gem install squeel

model.rb

```
Model.where{date_colum > 10.years.ago & date_column < DateTime.now}
```